# Find Vo in an op-amp - transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I have a schematic with this system and can't find out how it works:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feHsLi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do I find Vo in this network? Please explain it "for dummies".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvq8Vp.png)</sup>

Comment: Upload a schematic somewhere, link to it here, and someone will edit it into your question. This is unanswerable as is.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. do you think it would be just as easy to get 10 reputation and add the images manually?

Comment: BTW, a more descriptive title, without the exclamation points also leads to better answers and happier EEs.

Comment: @angelatlarge what I mean is that when you already have a schematic on your computer, I would recommend posting a link to an image of that, instead of redrawing the circuit. Editing the image in is way fewer work.

Comment: @Camil Staps: Yes! Though any method (link, CircuitLab, ASCII art) is better than nothing when schematic is called for.

Comment: @angelatlarge Absolutely agreed.

Comment: I GOT IT! oh, and sorry about the "!"'s in the title. I'm a little fried atm.

Comment: :( now that I've posted a bit more competently, can I not be voted down? Apologies for being a complete noob here.

Comment: Actually, a downvote was _removed_ after your edit.

Comment: *sheepish laugh*... thanks for cleaning up my post Camil... Like I said, I'm a bit fried.

Comment: so... uh... is anyone going to answer?

Comment: Seriously? You asked this only one hour ago. Give us some time.

Comment: Sorry. I got fooled by that little "ask an expert" program and thought this site was a little more... "chatty" then it really is. My bad all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to remember with linear op-amp circuits is that you can assume (without any serious error) that V+ and V- inputs are at the same potential. You can also assume that the resistor in series with V+ input has no effect on reducing the signal into the input V+.

With this in mind the voltage across R2 has to be 4V and the voltage on the emitter of Q1 has to be 12V. This is the answer, it's as simple as that.

To help you understand a bit more, the transistor Q1 plays no-part in making the voltage output bigger or smaller. The circuit could have been redrawn with OA1's output straight to where the emitter is and the transistor lost completely. This works exactly the same.

The reason some circuits build a BJT in is that it can provide more current drive down to 0V for when certain output loads are connected.

Comment: Ok, so wait, WHY is the voltage at 12V after the emitter? If it's coming out of the op amp at +15V, then that would put a 3volt drop across the transistor... and why isn't the gain 2, shouldn't there be 8 volts coming out to the transistor? In that case wouldn't a 4volt drop across R3 work just as well? (You begin to see why I spent 12 hours on this today.)

Comment: But if there's negative feedback, then it wouldn't be coming out at 15 volts... but then... GOD THIS STUFF IS SO CONFUSING. I'm having a serious chicken and the egg complex with this circuit.

Comment: O_O before anyone even thinks it, I want to stay FAR away from what's inside the 741 chip. If you have to go there... just say "because of the magic black box."

Comment: the gain equation for a negative feedback would be R3/R2, which is 100/50... which is 2. So why is the voltage coming out as 3x the input? I'm not saying you're wrong, I just want to know that I'm missing here. I built this thing in the falstad.com simulator and it said the same thing -- 12V. what I need to know is why, god almighty, WHY?

Comment: @Qprime - concentrate on V+ and V- inputs HAVE to be the same voltage. For this circuit it's 4V. Imagine you had a variable PSU connected across R3 and R2 (in series), what voltage would you need from the PSU to see 4V across R2? 12V is the answer. The Op-amp (via the transistor) cannot "live" with its inputs not at the same voltage so, it has to make them the same and "manufactures" a voltage at the emitter that makes V(R2) = 4V. Does this help? A non-inverting op-amp circuit gain is 1 + R3/R2 and it is this because of it needing to maintain the same volts on both inputs.

Comment: A) what's a PSU... And B) ok, I think I'm starting to see it. Is it to do with voltage divider across R3? Yes I get the nature of V+=V-, that's one of the only parts of the circuit i'm comfortable with (crazy as that seems)

Comment: OOOOH. wrong formula! I was using the inverting op amp formula... O_o that explains why the voltage isn't negative...

Comment: So the value of Vcc doesn’t make any never-mind whatsoever? When I experimented with it in a simulator it seemed to make all sorts of crazy things happen as it crossed about the 12 volt line.

Comment: Oh. P.ower S.upply U.nit. *all hail the power of google*

Comment: THANK YOU! 3210... sheesh, really? minimum characters? anyway, thanks all SO much for helping me with this!

Comment: @Qprime  no problem dude - I still remember being taught it many years ago and that majestic curtain rose to expose the full op-amp glory etc...

Comment: Another reason to embed a transistor in such a way is to use the current flowing through the resistive network in the emitter. An example is the current sink.